# Tabpage Scrollbar position not maintaining, always goes to the top position

Tags: c#, .net, scroll, tabs

In an application that I have written there is a form inside the main form that is composed of a tabcontrol with various tabPanels in it. I have the AutoScroll property of a tabPanel set to True so that if there are more clickable objects (buttons, checkboxes etc.) on the dashboard than can be visible on the screen, the user can scroll down to view and click on them. When the user clicks on one the clickable objects when going down the scrollbar, the scrollbar suddenly jumps up (not all the way up) out of position. When clicking the same object again, the scrollbar doesn´t move, but if another object is clicked then it moves up again.

Some of the solutions I have tried are the following:

-Using the clickable object handler (Click event) to set the tabpanel.AutoScrollPosition to the clickable object position.

-Overriding ScrollToControl method to return to the point associated with the currently visible portion of the tabPanel.

From the solutions that I have seen online, the overriding ScrollToControl solution seems to be the correct one, but I'm afraid that I may have not implemented it correctly.

To replicate the conditions of the original project in a simpler manner, I have created a simple project for you to see the code.

````
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override System.Drawing.Point ScrollToControl(System.Windows.Forms.Control ActiveControl)
        {
            return tabPage1.DisplayRectangle.Location;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollToControl(ActiveControl);
        }
    }```

Thank you very much for your help!

Best Regards.
````

Comment: I have solved the issue! I have solved it by setting the AutoScrollMargin property of the tabPanel to 0. Its value was 1000 before but after setting it to 0 the problem is gone.